# Replace word in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My dataframe contents

```
    comment
0   abg ko metedarah duit rakyat nak buat belanja ...
1   tutup tv n radio jgn dngar janji bajet 2 dr ta...
2   ya lah ko dah dera rakyat bajet besar untuk ra...
3   oiii kerjaan bn ko org sdr x dh lh kerajaan xd...
4   bertambah lg hutang negara diambil oleh tangan...
```

to be replace with list from file

```
    word    correction
0   abg     abang
1   n       dan
2   dr      dari
3   ko      kau
4   org     orang
```

Any possible way?

Comment: why is this even in a dataframe to begin with?

Comment: @acushner Thanks for asking. It refers to my csv file with 3 columns, 2000 rows, I've simplified it.

Comment: thanks. the reason i was asking is that a dataframe with a single column of strings really shouldn't be a dataframe and should probably just be a list or array, but if there are other related columns then that might make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using regular expressions with the `str.replace()` method in pandas to change instances of the words found at word boundaries(`\b`) and then replacing with the correction:

```
>>> data

                                          comment
0   abg ko metedarah duit rakyat nak buat belanja
1  tutup tv n radio jgn dngar janji bajet 2 dr ta
2  ya lah ko dah dera rakyat bajet besar untuk ra
3  oiii kerjaan bn ko org sdr x dh lh kerajaan xd
4  bertambah lg hutang negara diambil oleh tangan

>>> correction_df

  word correction
0  abg      abang
1    n        dan
2   dr       dari
3   ko        kau
4  org      orang

for word, correction in correction_df.itertuples(index=False,name=None):
    data.comment = data.comment.str.replace(r'\b{0}\b'.format(word),correction)

>>> data

                     comment
0    abang kau metedarah duit rakyat nak buat belanja
1  tutup tv dan radio jgn dngar janji bajet 2 dari ta
2     ya lah kau dah dera rakyat bajet besar untuk ra
3   oiii kerjaan bn kau orang sdr x dh lh kerajaan xd
4      bertambah lg hutang negara diambil oleh tangan
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @khammel, solution works! I read both from csv file as dataframe, and replace using your suggestion. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

is There are potentially better solutions, but here something dirty, that works:

```
comments = ["abg ko metedarah duit rakyat nak buat belanja",
"tutup tv n radio jgn dngar janji bajet 2 dr ta",
"ya lah ko dah dera rakyat bajet besar untuk ra",
"oiii kerjaan bn ko org sdr x dh lh kerajaan xd",
"bertambah lg hutang negara diambil oleh tangan"]

corrections  =
{"abg"  :   "abang",
"n"   :    "dan",
"dr" :      "dari",
"ko"  :     "kau",
"org"  :    "orang",
 }

data = pd.DataFrame(comments)
data.columns = ["comment"]

def correct(w,corrections):
    c =corrections.get(w)
    return c if c else w

def make_corrections(sent,corrections):
    return " ".join((correct(w, corrections) for w in sent.split()))

data.apply(lambda x: make_corrections(x.comment, corrections),axis=1)
```

The code loops through every word and replaces it with a correction if one exists. This takes time in the length of the corpus.

Comment: Thank you so much @putonspectacles. Great. The function works well. And I'm trying to refer the comment and correction from csv file's dataframe. Any suggestion? Thanks bro!

Comment: glad it helped. so your correction are in a dataframe instead of a dictionary?

Comment: Yes. khammel also gave the solution. Basically both works! Thanks again @putonspectacles.